# Не удается запустить сервер после установки

Tags: postgresql, установка

Доброго времени суток.

**Установил PostgreSQL со следующими параметрами:**

1. Версия - postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.14
2. ОС - Windows 10 (64 битная)
3. Место установки - S:\PostgreSQL (по умолчанию предлагалось установить на диск С, но я установил на другой диск, который использую для установки программ)
4. Установленные программные компоненты - PostgreSQL Server, pgAdmin 4, Command Line Tools
5. каталог базы данных для хранения данных - S:\PostgreSQL\data
6. Порт - 5432 (оставил по умолчанию)
7. Языковой стандарт - English (United States)
8. В переменную среды Path добавил два пути: S:\PostgreSQL\bin и S:\PostgreSQL\lib

**Вот что лежит в логах после установки (файл installation_sumary.log):**

```
Installation Directory: S:\PostgreSQL
Server Installation Directory: S:\PostgreSQL
Data Directory: S:\PostgreSQL\data
Database Port: 5432
Database Superuser: postgres
Operating System Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
Database Service: postgresql-x64-10
Command Line Tools Installation Directory: S:\PostgreSQL
pgAdmin4 Installation Directory: S:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4

===== Installation completed at: 2020-09-04(YYYY-MM-DD) - 15:56:23(HH:MM:SS) =====
```

**А вот содержимое логов из папки S:\PostgreSQL\data:**

```
2020-09-04 15:26:59.332 +06 [3552] LOG:  database system was shut down at 
2020-09-04 15:26:27 +06
2020-09-04 15:26:59.560 +06 [4768] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-09-04 16:23:43.365 +06 [4532] LOG:  could not rename temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp" to "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2020-09-04 16:23:48.083 +06 [8748] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

**Чтобы проверить, успешно ли прошла установка**, я попробовал запустить psql оставляя поля Server, Database, Port и Username со значениями по умолчанию. Во всех уроках по установке PostgreSQL которые я видел - после шага Username предлагалось ввести пароль, но у меня вышло это:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
find: `/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18': Permission denied
find: `/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-3472166243-3432434909-294888864-1001': Permission denied
find: `/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-3472166243-3432434909-294888864-1005': Permission denied
find: `/c/Config.Msi': Permission denied
find: `/c/Documents and Settings': Permission denied
find: `/c/PerfLogs/Admin': Permission denied
```

Я без понятия, зачем PostgreSQL лезит на диск С и что он там пытается найти. Пожалуйста, помогите понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: `зачем PostgreSQL лезит на диск С` - а это и не postgresql. И не psql тоже - он такие вопросы при запуске не задаёт. Видимо какая-то самодеятельность стороннего установщика (а он именно сторонний даже если скачан по ссылке с postgresql.org). В остальном по виндам ничем ответить не могу.

Comment: Что вы имели ввиду под "это и не postgresql. И не psql тоже - он такие вопросы при запуске не задаёт."

Comment: Прямым текстом то что и написано: psql не спрашивает при запуске Server/Database/Port/Username.